# Checar conexão com a internet

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como faço para checar a conexão com a internet utilizando Java Script.

Exemplo: Se a internet estiver indisponível, aparece um  com uma mensagem de aviso, se a internet estiver disponível, aparece um  carregando uma página.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o `navigator.online`, ele retornar um boolean sobre sua conexão com a intenet:

```
var online = navigator.onLine;
```

Usando o `alert`:

```js
alert(navigator.onLine == true ? "Conexão OK" : "Você não possui conexão com a internet");
```

Usando o `console.log`:

```js
console.log(navigator.onLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar solicitações **Ping** usando *Ajax* para outro servidor e testar se há uma conexão com o mesmo, pode-se usar o seu mesmo servidor, ou usar outro servidor:

```html
// Importa o JQuery
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function ping(host, port, pong) {
  var started = new Date().getTime();
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

  http.open("GET", "http://" + host + ":" + port, /*async*/true);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
      var ended = new Date().getTime();
      var milliseconds = ended - started;
      if (pong != null) {
        pong(milliseconds);
      }
    }
  };
  try {
    http.send(null);
  } catch(exception) {
    // erro na conexão
  }
}
    
    ping("google.com", "80", function(m){ console.log("Levou "+m+" millisegundos."); })
    
    </script>
```

---

Fonte da [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript).